# Equivalent of ruby code for PHP?

Tags: php, ruby

Equivalent of ruby code for PHP?

**PHP**

```
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
```

**RUBY**

```
uri = "https://bleutrade.com/api/v2/market/buylimit?apikey=my_api_secret&market=LTC_BTC&quantity=0.023&rate=0.345"
sign_array = [{apisign:"#{sign}"}]

response = RestClient.post(uri, sign_array, "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

When I run my server it throws `"{\"success\":\"false\",\"message\":\"Invalid apikey or apisecret\",\"result\":[]}" error.`

I checked My api key and secret are correct but it is not accepting the post http method I request to get the information. Is my equivalent code correct?

Comment: What happens if you do `print_r(file_get_contents(https://bleutrade.com/api/v2/market/buylimit?apikey=my_api_secret&market=LTC_BTC&quantity=0.023&rate=0.345));` ?

Comment: @Darren - Throws the same error {"success":"false","message":"Invalid apikey or apisecret","result":[]}

Comment: And what if you accessed it directly in the browser? (*pasted into the address bar*)

Comment: @Darren - Getting the same error

Comment: Can you try get a new api key and see what happens with that?

Comment: @Darren - Did that also. the same happens